# javascript: math expression and substitute variables

Tags: javascript

I get two inputs:

1. math equation string

```
equation_string = "a * x**3 + b * x**2 + c * x + d"
```

2. variables

```
vars = {
  a: 1
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
}
```

Now i want to generate various math expression strings replacing with vars.

```
function(s, vars){

   substitute vars values in s <-- HOW to do this

   return replace_string
}
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67261455/edit) to include your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic since this amounts to a request for a math library. However, math.js is the library to do this: https://mathjs.org/examples/expressions.js.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) statement with `eval`. Only use this if you or a trusted source is creating the expression and not from another user's input.

```js
function evaluate(exp, obj) {
  with(obj) {
    return eval(exp)
  }
}

const variables = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  x: 5
}

console.log(
  evaluate("a * x**3 + b * x**2 + c * x + d", variables),
  evaluate("a + b + c", variables)
)
```